# Mapping values between numpy arrays and categorizing it

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, dictionary-comprehension

Novice in python!
A numpy array A of 1000 elements consists of fixed values between `-100` to `+100`. These 201 values are nothing but categories. Another numpy array B has the approximations of the values for each category of A. Both A and B are of same length.
For example `A=[-100, -100, -88, 87, 85, 32, 32, 32]` and corresponding
`B=[-100.3, -100.1, -86.5, 87.3, 85.5, 32.6,32.1,32.5]`. I want to get the corresponding approximated data for each category. In the above example

```
for -100:-100.3, -100.1  
for 32:32.1,32.6,32.5
```

I could not seem to get it working with dictionary and zipping

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [mre].

Comment: Thanks! I tried ``` z=zip(A,B)``` . Warning: Zip object cannot be called.  So I tried initializing dictionary with null keys as d=dict.fromkeys(list(A),[]).  Warning unhashable type:'numpy.ndarray'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a good truck thinking about dictionaries and zip.
What you really want is to iterrate through your A unique values and append values to a dict with keys these values. Using list comprehension it can be almost an one-liner. For example:

```
A = [-100, -100, -88, 87, 85, 32, 32, 32]
B = [-100.3, -100.1, -86.5, 87.3, 85.5, 32.6, 32.1, 32.5]

values_dict = {i: [] for i in set(A)}  # Initialize dictionary with empty lists
[values_dict[pair[0]].append(pair[1]) for pair in zip(A, B)]  # Append values to corresponding key.

print(values_dict)
```

Which prints:

```
{32: [32.6, 32.1, 32.5], -88: [-86.5], 85: [85.5], 87: [87.3], -100: [-100.3, -100.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy if you get into a pandas dataframe.

```
# A=[-100, -100, -88, 87, 85, 32, 32, 32] 
# B=[-100.3, -100.1, -86.5, 87.3, 85.5, 32.6,32.1,32.5]

def retrieve_values(A, B):
   dict_values = {}
   df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A, 'B':B}).set_index("A")
   grouped = df.groupby('A')
   for index, val in grouped:
     dict_values[val.index[0]] = np.squeeze(val.values,axis=1)
   return dict_values

Output:

{-100: array([-100.3, -100.1]),
 -88: array([-86.5]),
  32: array([32.6, 32.1, 32.5]),
  85: array([85.5]),
  87: array([87.3])}
```

Comment: This answer was very helpful! It opened up lot of options.